# QBO3 Attachment Templates - header images from a URL

Tags: ms-word, imaging

We have hundreds of attachment templates in QBO that are based on Microsoft Word templates, and each embed our company logo in the header.

Rather than having the template show the header and footer in each document we would like to consider the possibility of saving the Headers & Footers as Images in QBO and just having the Template reference the saved image when it generates the letters.

We are not sure how or where the image would be stored and how the reference in the attachment template would work.

Answer (score 1):

Word is capable of using images from any URL in the document, as [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/38870/in-microsoft-word-how-can-i-link-to-an-image-from-the-web-which-updates) and [in a video](https://youtu.be/_VglLtj7rsc). For your use case, consider using images stored on your corporate website, rather than storing the images in QBO.

[image]

As with all records in QBO, users must log in to access them, so images stored in QBO would require the user (in this case, the person opening the merged Word document) to log in to view the header.

Comment: You could also "make do" with any number of free sites, such as [pasteboard.co](http://pasteboard.co/). Here's a [sample](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GWXoXQC.png). It's reasonable to test Word documents linking to such a site, while you wait for them to be added to your corporate website.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this the link to the image needs to be one that the **server creating the document** (QBO, in this case) can access. If the image is located locally on your computer such as the image below then when creating the document you will get a red x instead of the image.

[image: Image location for merging]

If the link is to a location that is publically available (like your corporate website), Word will be able to render the image in the document **regardless** of where Word is running.

[image]